# NetLogo: track and measure real turtle movement?

Tags: debugging, distance, netlogo

My turtles can jump / move forward over the world with correlated random walk. How can I simply measure a distance they have walked over my simulation run? Primitives `distance` and `distancexy` seem to measure the shortest distance between 2 points, not really the "curved" one. I have tried to google the answer but I can't find any possible  solution. Is it possible?
Also, when I'm using "pen-down" to track turtle movement, it starts from the second movement not from the first one. Any ideas why? It doesn't depends of the position of the `tick` in `go` procedure. Thank you very much !

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't proivided any code I cannot say what's wrong with your model, but I tried your problem with a very simple configuration

```
turtles-own[
   dist
]

to setup

   clear-all
   ask n-of 10 patches [sprout 1]
   ask turtles [pen-down set dist 0]

end

to go 

   ask turtles [
      rt random 90
      lt random 90
      fd 1
      set dist dist + 1 
      set label dist
   ]

end
```

Each turtle at each tick turns in a random direction and moves forward.

Each turtle has an own called `dist` that increases at each step it makes and it's shown as its label. (so that in every moment you can see the total distance turtles have walked, but it's always accessible for other purposes)

Each turtle has `pen-down` activated to draw all its movements. My suspect is that in your model you activate `pen-down` for all turtles after the movement phase, so in the first step turtles do not draw anything.

Comment: Thank you @dr_stein ! Your solution works great if my turtles move just by fd 1. The problem is that they can move fd random number and in this case measure of the distance doesn't work (set dist dist + 1). But your solution navigated me to another way how to measure walked distances using local variables - I put it into answer below. Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

Another answer based on @dr_stein suggestions - in case if my turtles walk by random number of steps (`fd random 4`), not by stable `fd 1`. Thus I implemented using of local variable `my_dist` - generate the random number and this number is used in both dist measure and in turtle movement.

```
turtles-own[
   dist
]

to setup    
   clear-all
   ask n-of 1 patches [sprout 1]
   ask turtles [pen-down set dist 0]
end

to go     
   ask turtles [
      rt random 90  lt random 90 ; rotate turtle heading
      let my_dist random 4      ; create local variable my_dist (generated one time)
      fd my_dist                ; move forward using local variable distance 
      set dist dist + my_dist   ; include this distance into dist calculation 
      set label dist
   ]    
end
```